# How to add a year in a calculated column?

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
DateTable=CALENDARAUTO()
```

Calculated columns:

```
NextYearDate = DATEADD(DateTable[Date],1,YEAR)
```

The above calculated column shows blanks instead of the next years date. Why is that and how to fix it?

Comment: Is the `DataTable` / `DateTable` difference a typo, or is your date table actually called `DataTable` ?

Comment: Yes I have corrected it now in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DATEADD` is a Time Intelligence function, which returns dates from your date column shifted by the specified interval. This means that for the latest year in your date table, there are no "next year" values to return.

An alternative would be:

```
NextYearDate = 
    DATE ( 
        YEAR ( DateTable[Date] ) + 1,
        MONTH ( DateTable[Date] ),
        DAY ( DateTable[Date] )
    )
```